# RESTful for Axon Repositories

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, axon

PROBLEM: Application uses **[Axon Framework](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/)** and `org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingRepository` and building `_links` in **HAL** format is needed in responses.

RESEARCH: Can be tuned with **[Spring Hateoas](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/)**, but a lot requires to be handcoded in rest-controller. **Spring Data REST** offers autogeneration of links with an only annotation on CRUD repository. The project is not RDBS & JPA-based, so **[Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html)** is not an option.

QUESTION: Does **Axon** offer any *RESTful* solutions from the box, or is there a better autoconfigured alternative to **Spring HATEOAS**?

Comment: Just for my understanding, but are you trying to have the `EventSourcingRepository` as a queryable thing through REST? For that matter, any `Repository` implementation provided by Axon?

Comment: This is a cqrs-command service. So RESTful is intended to accept commands and return 202 with uuid and _links on possible other commands on resource (aggregate). But it'll also be needed for cqrs-query service in the nearest future.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha, so you are essentially looking to expose a service's capabilities when it comes to which commands can be handled by a given Command Handling Component, disregarding whether that component is an [Aggregate](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/aggregate) or an [External Command Handler](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/external-command-handler).

Note, that interaction between a component which dispatches commands and one which handles them resides within the `CommandBus`. When an Axon application starts up, it's the `CommandBus` which receives all the registrations for known command handlers.

That way, the `CommandBus` provides the [location transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_transparency) for this part of the application. And it's location transparency which provides clear and cleanly segregated components; essentially what will help you to take an evolutionary microservices approach (as AxonIQ describes [here](https://axoniq.io/resources/microservices)).
I'd thus argue the necessity of sharing all known command handlers on a given service/aggregate through REST.

Regardless, whether it makes sense is always a question of "it depends". I for one have created a means to share the known commands a service could handle as JSON schema, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/ESarch/blob/master/trader-app/src/main/java/io/pivotal/refarch/cqrs/trader/app/controller/CommandController.java) in a sample project I helped built between AxonIQ and Pivotal.

So, to come round to your question:

> QUESTION: Does Axon offer any RESTful solutions from the box, or is there a better autoconfigured alternative to Spring HATEOAS?

No, Axon does not provide something like this out of the box, as it expect you use the `CommandBus` for communication. I do know you might need a starting point somewhere, for which REST makes sense, but even then exposing **all** known commands can be regarded as exposing your internal domain to the outside world. In the majority of scenarios, that would be undesirable, but as stated this highly "depends" on your use case.

Comment: Grateful for assitence and examples. Idea of internal microservices communication is clear and CoomandBus was not intended to be ingored. The RESTful requirement is to open some commands to the external clients outside of the microservices ecosystem - frontend apps that will initiate backend commands using REST endpoints. Then some manual coding in controllers needs to be done to describe _links HAL-style or actualize backend changes. I was wondering if Spring + Axon has some assistence to automate this, like Spring Data REST does. It would be wonderful to find this feature in future.

Comment: Gotcha @Zon, the idea isn't too off at all if you ask me. As current lead for the framework, I'll keep this idea in mind; might indeed be worth introducing at some point.